# How to call or write an Oracle function

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

Hi I am coding a Library Management System using JSF 2.2 and Oracle XE. I have Books and and Authors tables. In JSF I have books and authos pages. In Books page user can enter book and book's editor's name and it write it to Editor attribute in database. I want to write an Oracle function which takes Editor's name and insert it to Author table. In Author table there is Name and Surname attributes. So function should take a row from editor seperates it to Name and Surname and insert them to Author table. For this I coded below code. I took and seperated Editor names and surname. And passed them to a String array. The problem is Oracle Function. I do not know how to write it. How will we control Author table if this author is already in this table. Sure I do not want to add same people to table. I looked to internet for this but have nothing. If this question is so easy I am so sorry. Please help me. I will appretiate for this. Thanks.

```
public void AuthorNames() throws SQLException{
    String authorNames = "";
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","Alparslan-PC","123456");
        ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT EDITOR FROM BOOK");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        for(int count = 0; rs.next(); count++){
            authorNames += " " + rs.getString("EDITOR");
        }

        for(int count = 0; count<authorNames.length(); count += 2){
            NameSurname = authorNames.split(" ");
        }  

        sqlFunction(NameSurname);



    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BorrowerBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
public void sqlFunction(String[] NameSurname) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","Alparslan-PC","123456");
        for(int count = 0; count < NameSurname.length; count++){
            ps = con.prepareStatement("CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION author_names( " + NameSurname[count] + " , "
             + NameSurname[count+1] + " RETURN 0 ");
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BorrowerBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't create a function in your jdbc code.  That should be done externally. Why can't you just do a simple INSERT call?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I will code function in Oracle database and run it from Java. The answer for your question is this is a homework. We have to add a function or a procedure or a trigger in our project homework. Otherwise I can write an insert statement like you said.

Comment: Okay forget about function or procedure. How can I write INSERT INTO statement with controlling the existing people in database. I mean I must control people that I want to add is not already on table. How to make this control

Comment: One way yo get control: If the table has constraints on it - like no duplicate "people" in the table.